# Not able to use Integer type in for each loop

Tags: java, arraylist, foreach

Here's a method that returns an ArrayList of integers:

```
public List<Integer> primeFactors() {
        List<Integer> primeFactors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        if (num == 1) return primeFactors;
        for (int i = 2; i * i <= num; i++) {
            while (num % i == 0) {
                primeFactors.add(i);
                num = num / i;
            }
        }
        if (num > 1) {
            primeFactors.add(num);
        }
        return primeFactors;
    }
```

and here is the code which is calling the method:

```
List primeFactors = prime.primeFactors();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Integer i: primeFactors) {
            sb.append(String.valueOf(primeFactors.get(i)));
            sb.append(" ");
        }
```

But it's not working. It says "Incompatible types. Found: 'java.lang.Integer', required: 'java.lang.Object'" in line `for (Integer i: primeFactors)`

I don't know what's happening here as it works when I use ArrayList which is not returned from a method.

Comment: Why are you using a raw list here `List primeFactors = prime.primeFactors();` instead of how you did it before `List<Integer> primeFactors = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

Comment: prime will hold `n`, i guess. I would advice to using static methods instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly tell the compiler what type the objects in the list will be:

```
List<Integer> primeFactors = prime.primeFactors();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Integer i: primeFactors) {
            sb.append(String.valueOf(primeFactors.get(i)));
            sb.append(" ");
        }
```

and it should work just fine.

I would consider changing `primeFactors()` to `public static List<Integer> primeFactors(int n)`. There is no need to deal with instances.